# How to view linux hidden process and remove rootkit

Tags: linux, centos5

I and just installed OSSEC and it is telling this

```
Process '2517' hidden from /proc. Possible kernel level rootkit.
Excessive number of hidden processes. It maybe a false-positive or something really bad is going on.
```

Its my live server and i host around 20 sites on it.

How can i remove that. and what maximum damage it can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see that hidden process every time you run OSSEC? If you see it only once, it could be that there was a delay between when OSSEC got the info from `ps` (say) and then it checked it against /proc. In the meanwhile the process may have terminated, raising the alert you just saw.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be a good thing to install and run [**rkhunter**](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/). If this confirms that you have been compromised then your only realistic action is to make a copy of the compromised server to analyse later then reinstall from scratch and recover using known good backups.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that OSSEC is using the `unhide` utility to check for hidden processes. This tool sometimes raises false-positives.

You can check yourself by running
`unhide proc` or `unhide-linux26 proc` for a 64bit system.