# Find the process listening on a port (not showing in lsof)

Tags: linux, port, process, udp, netstat

**Update:**

The port was opened by NFS. I figured this out by configuring NFS to listen on a known port.

---

Using Ubuntu 18.04

I want to know which process or kernel function listens on **UDP port 38637**.

I have researched this problem and found similar questions:

- https://superuser.com/questions/42843/finding-the-process-that-is-using-a-certain-port-in-linux
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35292/quickly-find-which-files-belongs-to-a-specific-inode-number
- [Network port open, but no process attached?](https://serverfault.com/questions/51499/network-port-open-but-no-process-attached)
- [netstat shows a listening port with no pid but lsof does not](https://serverfault.com/questions/311009/netstat-shows-a-listening-port-with-no-pid-but-lsof-does-not/847910#847910)
- [Permission denied on /proc/ some process](https://serverfault.com/questions/188850/permission-denied-on-proc-some-process)

I have tried all remedies I could find...

- Unmounted all network drives
- Rebooted. After reboot the same port listens.
- Ran virus/trojan scans with clamav and sophos-av
- `nmap` and `nc` both successfully connect on the port
- Tried all the following inspections:

### netstat

Shows no process ID

```sh
➜ sudo netstat -ulpen | grep 38637
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38637           0.0.0.0:*                           0          36601      -
udp6       0      0 :::38637                :::*                                0          36602      -
```

### lsof

Shows nothing at all

```sh
➜ sudo lsof -i udp:38637
➜ echo $?
1
```

### rpcinfo

Doesn't list the port of interest

```
➜ sudo rpcinfo -p | grep 38637
➜ echo $?
1
```

### fuser

Troubling?

```
➜ sudo fuser -n udp 38637
Cannot stat file /proc/16147/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/16374/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/16375/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/16380/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/16381/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/16382/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/18061/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/18177/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/18183/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/18188/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/18189/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/18190/fd/1023: Permission denied
```

inode doesn't give me anything either

```
➜ sudo fuser --inode 36601
Specified filename 36601 does not exist.
```

### debugfs

Nada.

```
➜ sudo debugfs -R 'ncheck 36601' /dev/sda1
debugfs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Inode   Pathname
```

I would appreciate any other suggestions on where to look for answers on why this port listens.